# Is it possible to check route param data type in dynamic routes with Nuxt JS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Basically I have the following nested dynamic route

```
pages/
--| _category/
-----| _page.vue
-----| _id.vue
```

I want to use the page component when the `_page` param is an `integer` and use the id compnenet when it is a string.

Example

`/pages/phones/1` -> page component

`/pages/phones/6105565f363abdcce20fc189` -> id component

Comment: maybe you can use `/pages/phones/id-:id` and `/pages/phones/page-:page` instead of them, but in my opinion, `/pages/phones?page=1` may be a better choose compared with `/pages/phones/1`

Comment: unfortunately I cannot change the urls because of SEO. `/pages/phones?page=1` is definitely a good idea, but it is too late for that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `is` in your `/pages/_category/_param.vue` nuxt-page-component:

**/pages/_category/_param.vue**

```js
<template>
    <component :is="el" :id="param" :page="param"/>
</template>
<script>
import Show from './_id.vue';
import Index from './_page.vue';
export default{
    components: {
        Show, Index
    },
    props: {
        param: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        el(){
            return /[a-zA-Z]/g.test(this.param) ? 'show' : 'index';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```